# Apache mod_perl2 migration problem

Tags: apache, apache2, mod-perl2, perlsections

I have an apache2 config file under /etc/init.d/apache2/conf.d/  which uses Perl Sections.

I am just trying to test if a module is loaded and configure apache as appropriate.

```
if( Apache->module( "mod_ssl.c" ) )
{
  ...
} else { ... }
```

This is the error I see though when restarting.  I've also tried Apache2->method but get same error.

> # /etc/init.d/apache2 restart
> Restarting web server: apache2Building Appliance configuration for Debian 5.0.7
> Syntax error on line 73 of /etc/apache2/conf.d/foobar.conf:
> \t(in cleanup) Can't locate object method "module" via package "Apache" (perhaps you forgot to load "Apache"?) at /etc/apache2/conf.d/foobar.conf line 357.\n
>  failed!

I don't think it is an @INC problem... And apache and libapache2-mod-perl2 packages are both installed.  In fact if I comment that line out the rest of the perl actually runs fine.

```
perl -e 'print join "\n",@INC'
/etc/perl
/usr/local/lib/perl/5.10.0
/usr/local/share/perl/5.10.0
/usr/lib/perl5
/usr/share/perl5
/usr/lib/perl/5.10
/usr/share/perl/5.10
/usr/local/lib/site_perl
```

I've also tried using the Apache::compat and "Apache2->module".
I suspect the problem is something is missing in startup.pl - but I've been googling and reading the mod perl docs and going round in circles.  Any suggestions stackoverflow???

BTW-  my startup.pl:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use strict;
use lib qw( /usr/lib/perl5/ /usr/lib/perl5/Bundle /usr/lib/perl5/Apache2 ) ;

BEGIN
{
    use Apache2 ();
    my $hostname = `hostname`;
}
use Apache;
use Apache::DBI ();
use Apache2::Const ();
use Apache2::Log ();
use Apache2::URI ();
use Apache2::compat;
use LWP::UserAgent ();
use DBI() ;

1;
```

Answer (score 0):

[The documentation](http://perl.apache.org/docs/2.0/user/porting/compat.html#C_Apache____Methods) on porting from 1.0 to 2.0 suggests `Apache2::Module::loaded()`